# Get URL contents from a sign-in site

Tags: php, url, file-get-contents

I want to get the source code of a site using PHP, but when I do it comes up empty.  I believe it is because you have to sign in to the site before using it, and the PHP call is not in a signed in session when asking for the contents.  Is this correct? Is there a way to bypass this or send the sign in user and pass by PHP, so the call can be made later?

I also tried logging in via my browser  to the site and then calling my *.php file in my localhost from the same browser, but it didn't work.

This is an example of a required sign-in site where I want to get the source when opening my mailbox. This is the way I would normally get the site contents.  But it comes up empty:

```
$url = "http://mail.yahoo.com/mc/welcome".$params;
$pagesource = file_get_contents( $url );

echo $pagesource;
```

This code works if you call it for example, with `$url = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/432539/elcool" ;`  which is my profile page and is available publicly without needing to sign in.

Any ideas?

Comment: The way the site knows whether you are signed in or not is by the session ID (and possibly other stuff) stored in the cookie, so you'd have to duplicate the cookie that your browser is sending. I can't think of an easy way to do that off the top of my head but it is certainly possible.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use something like [cURL](http://php.net/curl) to emulate the log-in form and send the POST request to the remote server.

See this post here for a simple example:
http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl

I would, though, see if the remote site offers an API that you can use to authenticate and get the data you're looking for, because the method you're implementing (named [*Web Scraping*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)), is unreliable and may even be illegal, depending on the remote site's Terms of Service.

Comment: Yeap, tried cURL too, but just a simple version and didn't work. I'll check out the rest of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, first you will need to make a login call to whatever the page is, and use the `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` settings to keep track of the session when making calls as an authenticated user using [curl_setopt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).